# Why is my plane flickering in solid view mode?

Tags: 3d-view

My 5 sided plane is flickering when rotated in solid view mode

The plane has only one face and doesn't have any inner edges, I have tried creating another plane and it doesnt look like it has this problem.

Why would my plane flicker like that?[image]

Comment: Have you checked for double vertices with Remove Doubles [W]?

Comment: As @Leander said you can resolve this issue by removing doubles. You have two copies of the mesh on top of each other causing Z-Fighting artifacts in the viewport

Comment: @Leander Yes I have made sure to remove doubles, there weren't any

Comment: @SamirRahamtalla the other plane in the picture is the one I was trying to make to confirm that there is nothing wrong with my blender, it was at another point in the z-axis

Comment: It may help to upload a condensed version of your file with only the plane in question to blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and post the link in an edit to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Next to viewport shading buttons go into the options menu, and check "Backface Culling".
NOTES:
(1) When solid shaded objects get larger for the units of measurement used (mm or m?) it may cause flicker that does not occur on small objects.
(2) With backface culling enabled, you will only see faces from the outside, where the normals are set. This is OK for solid volumes, but when removing faces from a solid in edit mode, you may want to disable backface culling.